# Android - how to check was my app installed to device before?

Tags: android, sqlite

My app gives 200 coins on the first installation. A user can use these coins to perform an action in an application. The number of coins is stored in the SQLite database and can be changed. If you uninstall and install the app number of coins returned (Becomes again 200 coins)

#### I do not want users to reinstall the app when they have 0 coins and return the original number of coins

I tried to write down the database in the SD card. But what if there is no SD card and what if the user gets access to the database and can change it?

## So maybe I can check was app installed before?

Or how I can solve this problem another. So my application works without the server part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should know that even if you can detect the application has previously installed on their device, they can simply format their phone.

Then how do I solve this problem?

> You should have an **online database that stored the users coin**. Why? Because no matter how many times the users reinstalled or format their device, they can't alter the coins.
>
> You can still use SQLite as your database for your application. Just simply store the coins seperately.

Comment: For online database I have to write a web service?

Comment: What do you mean by web service? For online db, you can write a script where it reads data from database. Then, each time the user install the application, you calls the scripts to read users coin.

Answer (score 1):

Just to check if app was installed on the device before or not, you do not need to write the whole database on the sd card.

Secondly , you will write on the internal storage and not on the SD card.
It does not matter if SD card is present or not.

Now , just to check whether app was previously installed or not on the device you can do the following :

When app is first time installed on a device, create a folder named temp or any name which a user will ignore.

Now whenever the app is run, you can simple check whether that folder exists or not ? If that folder exists means the app was already installed if that folder does not exist, means this is the first time the app is installed.
Instead of creating a folder you can also create an empty file and check if the file exists or not.

Let me know if you need some more help.

Comment: What happen if the user delete this temp folder? Doesn't it reset the coins?